# No Error with my code, function returns no result

Tags: python-2.7

I've made this function for a **`HW`** but every time I run it python returns no result,

What am I doing wrong?.

### mult

```
def mult( n, m ):
    """ input two strings
        output the product of those numbers
    """
    if n==0 or m==0:
        return 
    elif m<0:
        m=abs(m)
        m+m
        mult(n-1,m)
        return 
    else:
        m+m
        mult(n-1,m)
        return
```

Comment: you'll need to fixup your spacing or it's difficult to tell what might be the problem in a space-sensitive language such as python

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but none of your return statements return any values; that would be a good place to start...

Answer (score 2):

In Python `return` is a transtive verb. It is sort of like the verbs "say" or "go"

say *what*? go *where*? return *what*?

You seem to think of `return` as something which simply returns execution flow to the caller (perhaps returning the value of the last calculated expression) but it doesn't work that way.

```
def add(x,y):
   return x+y
```

returns the sum of x and y

```
def add(x,y):
    x+y
    return
```

returns nothing (which is called `None` in Python). It computes the sum of x and y but then discards the result.

Answer (score 1):

Think about `return` as "give to the guy who called me".

```
def four():
    return 4

print("four is ", four()) # four is 4
```

So, if I need a four, I can call my handy new function: `print("four is ", four())`. `print()` calls `four()` to get a result. If I define `four()` with an empty return statement, it won't give me anything.

```
def four():
    4
    return

print("four is ", four()) # four is None
```

`return` with recursion is the same "giving to the caller" principle, only more complicated.

```
def add(n,m):
    """add two integers together. The second integer
    cannot be negative"""
    if m == 0:
        return n
    else:
        return 1 + add(n, m-1)
```

For simplicity's sake, the second number cannot be less than 0. Now, think about the algorithm, and how the `return <something>` affects it. If `m` is zero, then `n + 0 == n`, so we only need to `return n`. Otherwise, we're adding one to our eventual answer and subtracting one from `m`.

`add(2, 3)` becomes
`1 + add(2, 2)`(the `return` means "give to the guy who called me" which is `add(2, )`), which becomes `1 + 1 + add(2, 1)`, which becomes `1 + 1 + 1 + add(2, 0)`, and when we see zero in that second spot, we just replace it with the first number, so it becomes `1 + 1 + 1 + 2` which is `5`.